# Using ParametricNDSolveValue with initial conditions of another ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I have a system of parameter-dependent ODEs, which I can solve using `ParametricNDSolveValue`. Now, I have another ODE, which has as initial condition the solution of one component of the first system at a specific time point.

Consider the example

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == a*x[t], x[0] == 1}, {x}, {t, 0, 10}, {a}];
qfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[s] == a^2*y[s], y[0] == First[pfun[a]][2]}, {y}, {s, 0, 10}, {a}];
```

Then,

```
qfun[4]
```

gives the output: *ParametricNDSolveValue::ndinnt: "Initial condition 4.[2.] is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers"*.

This is odd, since `First[pfun[.5]][2]` produces $2.71828$ as output, as one expects.

However, omitting the curly brackets of `x` in the first line gives the correct result:

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == a*x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}, {a}];
qfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[s] == a^2*y[s], y[0] == pfun[a][2]}, {y}, {s, 0, 10}, {a}];
First[qfun[4]][2]
```

produces the output $2.35385*10^{17}$, which is $\exp(2a)\exp(a^2s)$ for $a=4$ and $s=2$.

As mentioned, `pfun` is a *system* of equations in the real problem, so omitting curly brackets is no option for me.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I found out that the problem  with the first two lines of code is that the fragment `First[pfun[a]]` is first evaluated with `a` having no value, thus `First[pfun[a]]` reduces to `a`. How can I specify that `First` is evaluated *after* `a` is given a specific value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks a little like the more common case where you want to evaluate only for numeric arguments. Here you want to only evaluate for lists, here is one way to achieve that:

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == a*x[t], x[0] == 1}, {x}, {t,0, 10}, {a}];

first[l_List] := First[l];

qfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {y'[s] == a^2*y[s],y[0] == first[pfun[a]][2]}, {y}, {s, 0, 10}, {a}
];

qfun[4]
```

for your more general case of a system of ODEs you might want to define something like:

```
part[l_List, n_Integer] := Part[l, n];
```

and then use it like:

```
qfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {y'[s] == a^2*y[s], y[0] == part[pfun[a], 1][2]}, {y}, {s, 0, 10}, {a}
];
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! However, I loose the possibility to calculate parameter sensitivities. But this seems to be a more general problem and will be the content of another question.

Comment: See here for the followup question on the parameter sensitivity: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/parameter-sensitivities-of-parametricndsolvevalue-involving-a-non-analytical-fun